# How to make Promise work synchronously in the loop (Node JS)?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am a pretty new one in node.js, I am a little bit in stuck with async/sync functions

I have such a method where the problem is that loop executes asyn way instead of expected sync one:

```
function myFooMethod(conn) {
     conn.query(`MY_QUERY_HERE`,
        function (err, result) {
           // Read list with all clients from backup
           let list = fs.readJSONSync(`${filesManager.appFolders.assetsFolder}/reports/customersList.json`, "UTF-8");
           match(backupList, result)
               .then(missingIds => {
                   if (missingIds.length > 0) {

                      missingIds.forEach((id) => {          <--------- THERE IS THE LOOP
                           if (id != null) {
                              console.log("FIRST STEP");
                              prepareAccountData(conn, id)   
                           }
                       });
                       
                       finalResult()     <--------- THIS code has to be performed after loop
                   }
               })
               .catch(function (err) {
               });
        })
    
}

function prepareAccountData(conn, id) {
    return new Promise(resolve, reject) => {
    conn.query(`MY_QUERY_HERE'`,
        function (err, result) {
            ....
            console.log("SECOND STEP");
        })
    })
}

function match(backupList, salesForceList) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       ...
        resolve(mismatchId)
    });
}


function finalResult() {
    .....
    console.log("THIRD STEP");
}
```

Expected result:

```
FIRST STEP 
SECOND STEP
FIRST STEP
SECOND STEP

THIRD STEP
```

actual result is:

```
FIRST STEP 
FIRST STEP
THIRD STEP
SECOND STEP
SECOND STEP
```

So somehow promises here are working async way... how to make them work sync?

**UPD**

```
function myFooMethod(conn) {
     conn.query(`MY_QUERY_HERE`,
        async function (err, result) {
           // Read list with all clients from backup
           let list = fs.readJSONSync(`${filesManager.appFolders.assetsFolder}/reports/customersList.json`, "UTF-8");

          let missingIds  = await  match(backupList, result);
           if (missingIds.length > 0) {
                       missingIds.forEach((id) => {          <--------- THERE IS THE LOOP
                           if (id != null) {
                              console.log("FIRST STEP");
                              prepareAccountData(conn, id)   
                           }
                       });
                       
                       finalResult()     <--------- THIS code has to be performed after loop
                   }
               })
               .catch(function (err) {
               });
        })
    
}
```

I got the same result, loop finishes with printing "FIRST STEP" twice, then the third step is performed
and after that the function **prepareAccountData** from the loop returns results "STEP THIRD"

Comment: You need to make your function `async` and use `await` on your database calls

Comment: You cannot make asynchronous code into synchronous code. What you *can* do, as mentioned, is use the `async` and `await` facility to make your code *look* like synchronous code, even though it still won't really be synchronous.

Comment: you might be interested in [`for await... of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-await...of)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the containing function `async`, then use `await`

```
    async function (err, result) {
       // Read list with all clients from backup
       let list = fs.readJSONSync(`${filesManager.appFolders.assetsFolder}/reports/customersList.json`, "UTF-8");
```

and await here

```
var missingIds = await match(backupList, result);

           //.then(missingIds => {
               if (missingIds.length > 0) {

                  missingIds.forEach((id) => {          <--------- THERE IS THE LOOP
                       if (id != null) {
                          console.log("FIRST STEP");
                          prepareAccountData(conn, id)   
                       }
                   });
                   
                   finalResult()     <--------- THIS code has to be performed after loop
               }
           })
           .catch(function (err) {
           });
    })
```

Comment: Please, look at updated code :)